# How do I hide the camera object in Unity Editor

Tags: unity

I have 2019 Unity Editor

I have a huge camera object that is blocking all the other objects that I need to move in the scene,

I want to hide this object, but I cannot find a hide/show menu item anywhere or when I right click on the hierarchy

[image]

Comment: Did you check the Gizmos menu?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it selectively... You can shrink all 3D icons from the Gizmo menu (top-right of the scene window), then using the 3D Icon slider